# Gnome terminal new tab behavior

Tags: linux, alias, gnome-terminal

I have an alias for `cd` command that does some additional logic before running actual cd (if you want the details, it activates virtualenv if it finds it in the directory). But when I open a new tab, `gnome-terminal` opens terminal in the same path without running my alias, so I have to do `cd .` every time to fix it.

Is there a solution for this? Maybe some kind of post-open-new-tab hook or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you define you alias somewhere in `~/.bashrc` or another file that is sourced by it, you can just append

```
cd .
```

to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Well, that was pretty obvious. Thank you, Dennis. :-) I'll accept you r answer as soon as restriction is off.